# how to find graph nodes based on a function?

Tags: d3.js, charts, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to build a d3 sankey graph
I have an array of nodes and links, but rather than using array indexes to define the links `0->1, 0->2` etc , I wanted to define links using named IDs. 
https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey#sankey_nodeId

I've got the link names all working, however, the d3 render fails with `Uncaught Error: missing: welcome`. It cannot find links by `id`

D3 graph docs talk about specifying a 'custom accessor' 
https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey#sankey_nodeId

But I can't figure out how to define this or pass it in.

I'm using some react code to generate the graph vis

https://codesandbox.io/s/m9vy7mr5k8?from-embed=&file=/src/MysteriousSankey.js

```js
    return (
        <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
            {nodes.map((node, i) => (
                <SankeyNode
                    {...node}
                    color={color(colorScale(i)).hex()}
                    key={node.name}
                />
            ))}
            {links.map((link, i) => (
                <SankeyLink
                    link={link}
                    key={'link-' + i}
                    color={color(colorScale(link.source.index)).hex()}
                />
            ))}
        </g>
```

Given that each node does have the `id` defined, I'm wondering how to tell the sankey renderer the way to find node for links by ID not default offset.
It seems this is also used in other D3 types of graph, and is referenced in this force graph
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f584aa36df54c451c94a9d0798caed35

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out. The structure for links with IDs is different from objects.

```js
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2,
            "value": 50
        },
```

OR

```js
    "links": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "some_id"
...
```